Is it possible for the residual variance in a model to be greater than the total variance of the variable being modeled?
I've fitted a linear regression in R with svyglm from the survey package. The data is weighted, and the model uses a ^2 transformation on the response to correct for non-normality.
I want to calculate the R-Squared for the model, I'm doing this using the formula: 1-residual variance/total variance.
In this case total variance = 4.48 and I'm getting the residual variance using the disperion parameter from the fitted model, this is a lot larger than the total variance (727.38). As the model includes a ^2 transformation, I tried sqrt(residual variance) in the calculation for R-Squared and the result is many times greater than 1.
So, two questions:

Is residual variance > total variance telling me something about the model I've fitted being  inappropriate?
Have I misunderstood something about accounting for the ^2 transformation in my model by using sqrt(residual var)?


Can you share your data and the code you used for calculations? Mathematically it is hard to see why a residual variance could be larger than total variance, but maybe your model is somehow misspecified, or you have some error in your calculations. We would need to know a bit more details to understand whats going on...

Answer this question: Is the square root of the variance of a squared variable equal to the variance of that variable?

If the residual variance exceeds the total variance, then you should be getting an $R^2$ value less than zero, not greater than one, yes? This is totally possible. We even have a [tag:negative-r-squared] tag for such a situation.

Sorry, this isn't really an answer but a thought, but it wouldn't fit in a comment:
I think you may be confusing variance of a variable with variance of a model. Here is some R code (anything after a # is a comment) for a very simple example.
set.seed(123)
x1 <- rnorm(1000, 0, .1)
x2 <- rnorm(1000, 0, .1)
y <- x1 + x2 + rnorm(1000, 0, 5)


var(y) #23.96
m1 <- lm(y~x1+x2)

anova(m1) #residual sum sq. = 23877

Here is the full table:
           Df  Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
x1          1     0.2   0.178  0.0074 0.9313
x2          1    57.0  57.032  2.3813 0.1231
Residuals 997 23877.6  23.949  

The total SS here would be the three SS in this table added up. That can't be lower than the residual SS, but the residual SS can be much greater than the variance of Y.
(If I've misunderstood, let me know and I will delete this)

The total variance is the variance of the dependent variable, no?

Never mind that question - you're telling me they're not the same thing. I've really misunderstood something here!

If I have answered your question, could you accept it by hitting the check mark? If I have not answered it, can you explain what's missing? Think of it this way. The variance of Y is the same, regardless of the model.
